# Create a column that flags when a certain value occurs in stacked data

Tags: r

I am working with a smoking variable. Some people said they "Quit" smoking, but at a later date, they say they have "Never" smoked. If "Quit" occurs, I would like to set all "Never" values to NA after the "Quit" event occurs (as it is bad data). I would like to do this for each person (HCI_PersonID)

Here is my data

```
SmokAlc<-
  structure(list(HCI_PersonID = c(1101261, 1101261, 1101261, 1101261, 
                                  1101261, 1101261, 1101261, 1101261, 1101261, 1101261, 1101261, 
                                  1101261, 1101261, 1101261, 1101261, 1101261, 1101261, 1101261, 
                                  1101261, 1101261, 1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 
                                  1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 
                                  1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 
                                  1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 
                                  1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 
                                  1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 
                                  1102406, 1102406, 1102406, 1103013, 1103013, 1103013, 1103013, 
                                  1103013, 1103013, 1103013, 1103013, 1103013, 1103013, 1103013, 
                                  1103013, 1103013, 1103013, 1103013, 1103013, 1103013, 1103013, 
                                  1103013, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 
                                  1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 
                                  1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 
                                  1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 
                                  1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 
                                  1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 
                                  1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 
                                  1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 
                                  1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 
                                  1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 
                                  1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 
                                  1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 1107341, 
                                  1110512, 1110512, 1110512, 1110512, 1110512, 1110512, 1110512, 
                                  1110512), CONTACT_DATE = structure(c(16374, 16731, 17039, 17410, 
                                                                       18277, 18285, 18302, 18302, 18303, 18303, 18395, 18485, 18646, 
                                                                       18667, 18927, 19100, 19151, 19270, 19334, 19340, 17179, 17212, 
                                                                       17268, 17310, 17410, 18796, 18806, 18807, 18809, 18822, 18837, 
                                                                       18843, 18848, 18849, 18857, 18879, 18900, 18921, 18942, 18963, 
                                                                       19003, 19016, 19017, 19024, 19102, 19128, 19131, 19137, 19205, 
                                                                       19221, 19254, 19258, 19265, 19305, 19339, 19369, 19374, 19380, 
                                                                       19403, 19473, 19486, 19499, 19509, 16316, 16680, 17133, 17136, 
                                                                       17165, 17169, 17184, 17198, 17220, 17303, 17308, 17394, 17484, 
                                                                       17681, 17681, 18031, 18388, 18752, 19116, 16703, 16728, 16736, 
                                                                       16757, 16797, 16903, 16904, 17100, 17409, 17448, 17463, 17766, 
                                                                       17787, 17814, 18121, 18171, 18179, 18197, 18199, 18200, 18208, 
                                                                       18213, 18219, 18246, 18400, 18404, 18529, 18550, 18590, 18596, 
                                                                       18598, 18610, 18666, 18715, 18718, 18771, 18773, 18897, 18898, 
                                                                       18899, 18903, 18925, 18925, 18932, 18932, 18960, 18990, 19016, 
                                                                       19030, 19037, 19045, 19046, 19067, 19072, 19100, 19128, 19128, 
                                                                       19130, 19136, 19158, 19184, 19185, 19199, 19205, 19206, 19212, 
                                                                       19212, 19216, 19241, 19256, 19268, 19296, 19324, 19331, 19338, 
                                                                       19339, 19387, 19395, 19415, 19464, 19465, 19501, 19523, 16568, 
                                                                       17520, 17550, 17560, 17575, 17583, 17583, 17589), class = "Date"), 
                 TOBACCO_USER = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
                                            4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
                 ), levels = c("", "Never", "Not Asked", "Quit", "Yes"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                           173L), class = "data.frame")
```

HCI_PersonID- the ID

CONTACT_DATE- the date the data was recorded. I am wanting to use it to reference whether a quit event happens before or after other data

TOBACCO_USER- the variable that identifies a person's smoking status

Comment: It will be simpler to test and demonstrate solutions if your example data reflects the condition you want to capture. HCI_PersonID 1103013 is the only one here with a "Quit," but they have no "Never" observations. I suggest editing the example data so they do.

Comment: I apologize for that oversight. I have hopefully provided better data now

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using `dplyr`.

First I arrange by `CONTACT_DATE` (and `HCI_PersonID` just to make the output easier to read). Then we can count the number of times each user has Quit, using `coalesce` so that NAs are ignored for that count. Finally, I make a new column (to show the change more clearly) that changes any row with `Never` but a prior `Quit` for that person to NA.

```
SmokAlc %>%
  arrange(HCI_PersonID, CONTACT_DATE) %>%
  mutate(cuml_Quit = cumsum(coalesce(TOBACCO_USER == "Quit", 0)), 
         .by = HCI_PersonID) %>% 
  # --- if using dplyr before 1.1.0, replace line above with ---
  # group_by(HCI_PersonID) %>%
  # mutate(cuml_Quit = cumsum(coalesce(TOBACCO_USER == "Quit", 0))) %>% 
  # ungroup() %>%
  mutate(TOBACCO_USER_new =
           if_else(TOBACCO_USER == "Never" & cuml_Quit > 0, NA, TOBACCO_USER))
```

Rows 77-83 of that output show the change:

```
 HCI_PersonID CONTACT_DATE TOBACCO_USER cuml_Quit TOBACCO_USER_new
1      1103013   2018-05-30         Quit        11             Quit
2      1103013   2018-05-30         Quit        12             Quit
3      1103013   2019-05-15         Quit        13             Quit
4      1103013   2020-05-06        Never        13             <NA>
5      1103013   2021-05-05        Never        13             <NA>
6      1103013   2022-05-04         Quit        14             Quit
7      1107341   2015-09-25        Never         0            Never
```

Comment: why does this logic set all of 1107341 to NA?

Comment: It doesn't do that for me, looks like all Nevers. I'm using dplyr 1.1.3, potential difference could be using dplyr <1.1.0, before `.by` was introduced. In that case, would need `group_by(HCI_PersonID) %>% mutate(cuml_Quit ....) %>% ungroup()` in place of that line.

Comment: I don't think it is a discrepancy with the version type. I am using 1.1.3. And actually, everything below 1103013 is NA. I am still trying to figure it out

Comment: I think it is with the other packages that are loaded. I tried with just loading dplyr, and your code worked

Comment: Gotcha. Fwiw, plyr::mutate does not see groups or have the .by parameter, so having plyr loaded after dplyr would give that result.